# Mouse Over Movie Clip is Buggy...It has text boxes on top that cancel the effect can I bypass this?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe

So I have a movieclip in my flash that has an event listener that calls it to pull up when the mouse is over and go down when the mouse is out. Kinda like a menu. But this object that I am accessing has text over it. The problem is it works until the the mouse that hits the text over it. Then it drops down.

I will paste my code if it helps...The code below is in the main timeline in scene 1.

```
//FeedBox Tween Stuff----------------------
var feedup:Tween = new Tween(FeedBox, "y", Strong.easeOut, 560, 290, 2, true);
var feeddown:Tween = new Tween(FeedBox, "y", Strong.easeOut, 290, 560, 2, true);

FeedBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseyOnFeed);
FeedBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseyOutBox);

function mouseyOnFeed(e:Event){
    feedup.start();
}

function mouseyOutBox(e:Event){
    feeddown.start();
}
```

Now the FeedBox has text over it in a text box that is generated from my twitter. This actionscript is actually in the library object.

```
var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
myXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=allencoded"));
myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML); 

function processXML(e:Event):void{ 
var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);

tweet1.text = myXML.status[0].text;
tweet2.text = myXML.status[1].text;
tweet3.text = myXML.status[2].text;
tweet4.text = myXML.status[3].text; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `mouseChildren` property of your movie clip false. Then the children (text in this case) will not interact with mouse.

```
FeedBox.mouseChildren = false;
```

Comment: Perfect worked like a charm...You wouldn't know why it is somewhat jumpy though? Am I missing a stop...it works but has areas that make is spaz out and jump up and down a trillion times.

Comment: AS3 event flow is defined is such a way that if a child generates an event then parent also get that. That means if parent is listening mouse out then event listener will be called when any child (text here) get a mouse out. This is not a bug, rather a feature and useful many times. By setting mouseChildren to false you disable this. Please go through to the Handling Events chapter form http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Part6_ProgAS_1.html for the technical details.

Answer (score 1):

Disable mouse events for children.

```
FeedBox.mouseChildren = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like feedbox is not the children. You have to remove text from event loop,

```
textfield.mouseenabled = false;
```

In your cases its like

```
tweet1.mouseenabled = false;
tweet2.mouseenabled = false;
tweet3.mouseenabled = false;
tweet4.mouseenabled = false;
```